# Make auto random phrases in same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I need help to make lot of random text to send on twitter but its too long copy paste any one know how i can duplicate `(rdmlol == 0):` to 500 Thank

Code

````
            
            if(rdmlol == 0):
                api.update_status(status = 'coucou les toxic de ma tl feur ' + str(TweetCount) + ' je ne suis pas un robot lol allez voir  feur ')
                
            elif(rdmlol == 1):
                api.update_status(status = 'coucou les pierre de ma tl feur ' + str(TweetCount) + ' je ne suis pas un robot lol allez voir feur')```
````

Comment: if the only difference is `toxic` and `pierre` then you could keep it as list and select (randomly) from list. OR use `data[rdmlol]` to get from list `data` based on `rdmlol`. And later you can create this list using data from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a for-loop over a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)?

```
for _ in range(500):
    msg = "coucou les toxic de ma tl feur " + str(TweetCount) + " je ne suis pas un robot lol allez voir  feur"
    api.update_status(status = msg)
```

If you need to construct a different message each time, the solution depends on what exactly do you need, e.g.

```
import random


def create_message(tweet_count, words):
    # f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6
    return f"coucou les {random.choice(words)} de ma tl feur {tweet_count} je ne suis pas un robot lol allez voir feur"


def update_status(api):
    words = ["toxic", "pierre"]
    for i in range(500):
        msg = create_message(i+1, words)
        api.update_status(status = msg)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for help i try use that and see if all are good and twitter don’t limit me